# Dart libsass compiles correctly but will not run

Tags: dart, libsass

I've follow the instructions for dart libsass at:
https://github.com/oddrationale/dart_libsass

The compile step completes correctly. However - when i try and execute sassd.dart i get the following:

```
dart bin/sassd.dart ~/projects/web_apps_dart/lib/client/components/picker/picker.scss ~/Desktop/test.css

Cannot find extension library'package:libsass/libsass.dart': error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dart-ext:libsass/src/sass_extension';
^

Cannot find initialization function in extension'package:libsass/libsass.dart': error: line 10 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dart-ext:sass_extension';
^

sass_extension.cc exists at ~/lib/src/sass_extension.cc
```

**Question**: How do we correctly import the sass_extions.cc file in recent builds of Dart?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author/maintainer of **dart_libsass**.

I got your [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/oddrationale/dart_libsass/issues/9) and resolved the issue there. The issue was with the build script not the `sass_extension.cc` file itself. If you have any other issues, let's continue the discussion on the GitHub issues page. Thanks!